# Что произойдет с переменной после return value++?

Tags: java, декомпиляция

Пример:

```
int foo() {
    int value = 0;
    return value++;
}
```

Метод вернет `0`, но что произойдет с переменной `value`? Будет ли компилятор генерировать код для `++`? Или оптимизирует? И как это проверить?

Comment: _КАК ЭТО ПРОВЕРИТЬ?_ - посмотреть сгенерированный код

Comment: С большой вероятностью JVM это оптимизирует и заинлайнит. Так что вместо вызова `foo()` останется литерал 0.

Comment: А зачем вам это проверять? Или вы собираетесь экономить на спичках?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#Java_compilers Здесь перечислено 6 компиляторов Java, но наверняка, это не все существующие. Вам придётся проверить код, сгенерированный каждым компилятором, причём, с разными ключами. Кто-то будет оптимизировать, кто-то нет. Но даже в этом случае вы не получите точного ответа на вопрос, потому что нет гарантий, что не напишут новый компилятор, который будет генерировать ещё какой-то код. И, как тут справедливо заметили, это ещё до того, как JIT подключиться к работе, он тоже умеет оптимизировать.

Comment: Зачем проверять - просто ради интереса, чтобы лучше понимать как работает компилятор

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Метод вернет 0, но что произойдет с переменной value? Будет ли
>   компилятор генерировать код для ++? Или оптимизирует? И как это
>   проверить?

Вот что я обнаружил когда открыл откомпилированный файл (с расширением .class) в Intellij IDEA. После декомпиляции код будет выглядеть так (в Java 8):

```
int foo() {
    int value = 0;
    byte var10000 = value;
    int var2 = value + 1;
    return var10000;
}
```

Компилятор создаст новую переменную `var10000` как вы видите в виде `byte` так как переменная `value` равна нулю и `byte` будет вполне достаточно и сэкономит нам памяти. Потом почему то создает новую переменную `var2` типа `int` и добавляет единичку и возвращает результат.

Если хотите проверить в других компиляторах, то в IDE выберете нужную Вам версию JDK, или даже можно пользоваться [jd декомпилятором](http://jd.benow.ca/) без IDE.

Comment: Прикольно. А чем вы декомпилировали?

Comment: В Intellij IDEA просто открываете нажав на файл с расширением .class в окошке Project.